# Comprobar login en Laravel 5.7 desde script externo

Tags: laravel, login, tinymce

Tengo una aplicación en Laravel y necesito comprobar, desde un script externo si hay un usuario logueado o no y cual es. Para ello uso las siguientes líneas de código, para cargar Laravel:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
    ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

/*if (Cookie::get(config('session.cookie')) != "") {
    $id = Cookie::get(config('session.cookie'));
    Session::driver()->setId($pericod);
    Session::driver()->start();
}*/

$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
if(!$isAuthorized){
    echo "NO AUTORIZADO";
    exit();
}
```

Con estas líneas tengo acceso a cualquier función de Laravel y de hecho, la comprobación de login me funciona correctamente para peticiones `GET`, pero cuando es una petición `POST` me falla, no es capaz de reconocer el login, de hecho, creo que reinicia la sesión porque no es capaz de recuperar la que existía.

He hecho muchas pruebas y creo que tampoco carga o usa ciertas partes del Laravel, como por ejemplo no reconoce las rutas, no carga los middlewares, etc...

Uso Laravel 5.7 actualizado hoy mismo y este mismo código me ha llegado a funcionar, creo recordar que en Laravel 5.4.

¿alguna idea de lo que puede estar fallando?

muchas gracias.

Comment: Has desactivado el csrf en las rutas post?

Comment: Si, lo he desactivado comentando el middleware y nada, tampoco es ese el error que da, siempre acaba en echo "NO AUTORIZADO";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He descubierto el problema.

El truco estaba en que la ruta del fichero php que cargo es externa a laravel, eso hace que el route resolver de laravel la identifique como que es /.
Todo estaba funcionando con peticiones `GET` porque en mi fichero routes.php de Laravel tengo la ruta / como tipo get. Si cambio el tipo de ruta a any, todo funciona correctamente.

No estaba viendo el problema porque no estaba terminando la ejecución de Laravel. Si cambio la parte de verificación de usuario logueado, si consigo ver el error:

```
$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
if(!$isAuthorized){
    echo "NO AUTORIZADO";

    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

    exit();
}
```

Estas dos lineas finalizan la ejecución de Laravel, haciendo que se desvele el problema real, mostrando el error: "405 Method Not Allowed".

```
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: recuerda que si tu respuesta resuelve tu problema la debes marcar como aceptada para que le sirva a otros usuarios y de paso el resto de la comunidad te la podamos votar positivo saludos